# How to retrieve an index from an object with one element only in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

After I do the following,

```
a = r[r.rar == "sth"]
print(a.rar)
```

I have

```
11    sometext 
Name: rar, dtype: object
```

Now, I want to retrieve the index (11) from this object-- the object is always going to have only one non-empty element.

I tried, but that did not work --

```
c=np.where(a[a.rar != ""])
print(c)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "did not work": what result do you get ?

Comment: What is `r`?  If not too larger, show us the whole thing.  If numpy array we need to know its shape and dtype.

Comment: @M. Massias The result was `(array([0, 0]), array([0, 1]))`

Comment: @hpaulj r is a 2-dim array [95 rows x 2 columns]

Comment: What sort of "object" is `r` (what is `type(r)`)?

Comment: @ali_m it is a dataframe (pandas.core.frame.DataFrame)

Comment: OK, that's a crucial piece of information! `r[r.rar == "sth"]` will return a new DataFrame consisting of a subset of the rows in `r`. What exactly do you mean when you say *"I want to retrieve the index (11) from this object"*? Do you want both columns in the 11th row where `r.rar == "sth"`?

Comment: @ali_m I just want "11". The result should be 11, i.e. the index of "sometext".

Comment: `a.index` should work? If only one row has sth, then `a.index[0]` would be safe too.

Comment: `r.index[r.rar == "sth"]`?

Comment: @ali_m Awesome- thank you. The first one returns 11, the second one  -Int64Index([11], dtype='int64')

Comment: Working with a `pandas` dataframe makes a big difference.  A `numpy` array does not have this sort of 'permanent' index.  `np.where` gives indexes nonzero values in the current array.

Comment: If this is about pandas, could you please mention so in the title and question?